# Javascript sort an array by subarray id

Tags: javascript

I have an array under `bahrein` that I would like ordered by the index of each item. My bare code is as shown below.

```js
var bahrein = [
{id: 1, name: "Josef"},
{id: 3, name: "Billy"},
{id: 0, name: "Jane"},
{id: 2, name: "Mack"}
];

for (i = 0; i < bahrein.length; i++){
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += "<p>"+bahrein[i].name+"</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

I have ids assigned for each item, but I placed them out of order. What I would like to know is how to programatically use the `sort()` function to list the names on my list in order.

Right now my innerHTML shows the list in the order they are written (ie: `Josef`, `Billy`, `Jane`, and `Mack`). I want to show them in the order of their ID (ie: `Jane`, `Josef`, `Mack`, `Billy`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort()` method on your data and then append it to html.

```js
var bahrein = [{id: 1, name: "Josef"},{id: 3, name: "Billy"},{id: 0, name: "Jane"},{id: 2, name: "Mack"}];
let show = document.getElementById("show")

bahrein
  .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
  .forEach(e => show.innerHTML += `<p>${e.name}</p>`)
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

You could also create string of sorted html and then append it html.

```js
var bahrein = [{id: 1, name: "Josef"},{id: 3, name: "Billy"},{id: 0, name: "Jane"},{id: 2, name: "Mack"}];

let sorted = bahrein
  .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
  .map(e => `<p>${e.name}</p>`)
  .join('')
  
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = sorted
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't answer your question, but you can use "lodash" to do the same.

```
var bahrein = [
    {id: 1, name: "Josef"},
    {id: 3, name: "Billy"},
    {id: 0, name: "Jane"},
    {id: 2, name: "Mack"}
];

bahrein = _.orderBy(bahrein , ['id'],['asc']);
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://lodash.com/).